# Responsive padding on navigation links

Tags: html, css, navigation, padding, percentage

I have a navigation bar which consists of two parts. The left area, which is where the actual links are. And the right area, which is were a search box will display.

The left area is fluid, while the right area has a fixed width.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to set the padding on my navigation links so that it will use up the full fluid width of the left area. (The navigation links are buttons with a hover effect, I would like them to cover the full navigation bar regardless of it's width)

See the example below

**What I'm trying to do (fluid/percentage based padding based on bar width)**

```
  width 300px
|========================================|========|
|---Link------Link------Link------Link---| Search |
|========================================|========|

  width 400px
  - padding on Links automatically adjusts to fill the bar
|================================================|========|
|----Link--------Link--------Link--------Link----| Search |
|================================================|========|
```

How would I go about achieving this? I've tried messing with padding percentages but I can't seem to get it to work as desired. Are padding percentages even the best way to go about this?

Comment: The answers given here are pretty good, but they did not answer exactly what I was trying to do. The navigation links ended up looking misaligned because each one of them got the same width, but the text inside the buttons were of different lengths. I might have worded my question poorly, so my excuses for that.

Just letting everyone know why I didn't choose a Best Answer.

I ended up just giving the links a fixed padding and changing it with Media Queries depending on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what support level you desire, you could use flexboxes.

I'll just assume you want to support older browsers, tho, where the best solution is propably a normal 2 column layout, with the links inside the left column getting a percentage width (25% in your example) and propably a `min-width`.

Heres a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhZLx/). I made the main box resizeable for easier demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

reduce the width of the container with padding and absolutely position the search box inside the padding. Here's an [example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OxEvUXO/8/edit)

HTML (note that some whitespace has been deliberately removed so that there aren't text nodes taking up space.):

```
  <nav class="">
    <div class="nav-link-container">
            <div class="nav-link"><a >link</a>
      </div><div class="nav-link"><a >link</a>
      </div><div class="nav-link"><a >link</a>
      </div><div class="nav-link"><a >link</a>
      </div>
    </div><div class="search-box-container">
      <input class="search-box" placeholder="search">
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  padding-right: 220px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
  .nav-link-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

  }
    .nav-link {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
      outline: 1px dashed grey;
    }
  .search-box-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;

    width: 210px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
    .search-box {

      width: 200px;

      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid lightgrey;
      padding-left: 5px
    }
```

NB: I've only used outline to show where the links are, you wouldn't do that in practise.